# GWT grails plugin ERROR resource.ResourceMeta - Resource not found: %nocache.js

Tags: gwt, grails, grails-plugin

I'm having trouble using the GWT-Grails plugin. I tried to follow this example exactly, but I end up having this error:

```
| Error 2012-10-28 00:25:49,567 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -  Resource not found: /gwt/g3wt.Application/g3wt.Application.nocache.js
```

I get this error after I enter these commands: ( I am simply following this guide [here](http://onlinevillage.blogspot.com/2010/05/while-html-5-holds-tremendous-promise.html) )

```
>grails create-app g3wt
>cd g3wt
>grails install-plugin gwt
>grails create-gwt-module g3wt.Application
>grails create-gwt-page main/index.gsp g3wt.Application
>grails run-app
>grails run-gwt-client
```

this is the index.gsp code (which is autogenerated anyway):

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Integrate with Sitemesh layouts           -->
  <meta name="layout" content="main" />

  <!--                                           -->
  <!-- Any title is fine                         -->
  <!--                                           -->
  <title>Example title (change this!)</title>

  <!--                                           -->
  <!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
  <!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
  <!-- be added before this line.                -->
  <!--                                           -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'gwt/g3wt.Application', file: 'g3wt.Application.nocache.js')}"></script>
</head>

<!--                                           -->
<!-- The body can have arbitrary html, or      -->
<!-- you can leave the body empty if you want  -->
<!-- to create a completely dynamic ui         -->
<!--                                           -->
<body>
  <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
  <iframe id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

  <!-- Add the rest of the page here, or leave it -->
  <!-- blank for a completely dynamic interface.  -->
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that the nocache.js cannot be found, so I thought I could try to see where exactly it is. However, using the eclipse search function, it shows that the file is not created at all. Although there is a file named application.js.

Why is the nocache.js not created, and how do I fix this? I've been stumped for a while now, and it's frustrating.

I'm using gwt plugin 0.7.1 and grails 2.1.1, with eclipse 4.2 and a Linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem and found the [answer here.](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-and-GWT-Plugin-resource-not-available-error-td4414349.html)

`buildconfig.groovy` is in the conf folder.  Just comment out the plugin where the runtime is ":resouces..."

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I got the error to disappear by first running

```
grails> compile-gwt-modules
```

Now a different problem occurs. The front-end gwt codes I made, aren't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in you Confing.groovy:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.excludes = ['**/gwt/**']
```

This will solve the problem. But if you use plugin version 0.8 this issue should be resolved.